# Read only visibles directory´s file names

Tags: java, arrays, list, file

Im trying to read the filenames of a folder an save them in an array list, but i get invisble files names in my array that i dont want(actually i want only to saves the .txt file names). Does anybody knows hor to change that in the code before creating the list?

```
String pathLevel= "/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/lvl/";

File file = new File(pathLevel);
String [] levelNames = file.list();


String [] matrix= new String[levelNames.length];
```

Comment: if i go to the folder.. mac os x they are not displayed.. i only see 5 .txt files

Comment: Hidden folders and files usually have a `.` at the start. Try filtering them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java.nio.file. Using Java 8:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get("/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/lvl/");

final List<String> textFiles = Files.list(dir)
    .filter(path -> !Files.isHidden(path))
    .map(path -> path.getFileName().toString())
    .filter(s -> s.endsWith(".txt"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If Java 7, do the equivalent with [`Files.newDirectoryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
final Path dir = Paths.get("/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/lvl/");

final DirectoryStream<Path> dirstream
    = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.txt");

final List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<>();

for (final Path entry: dirstream)
    if (!Files.isHidden(entry))
        textFiles.add(entry.getFileName().toString());
```