# read files names from directory without System files(.DS_Store)

Tags: java, arrays, list, filereader

Im trying to read all filenames from a folder and save them in an array but 
im still reading all files (including the system folder .DS_Storefrom)so that my code doesn´t work for what i want to do. anyone knows how to read only non Systems files/folder?
Thanks for the help!

Here´s what i wrote,

```
String pathLevel= "/Users/lan/Desktop/top/";


        File file = new File(pathLevel);
        String [] levelNames = file.list();
        String [] matrix= new String[levelNames.length];
```

Comment: You could use FilenameFilter, here is a [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932962/use-of-filenamefilter)

Comment: Again: [I already answered that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28289545/1093528); why do you keep asking the same question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read only visibles directory´s file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289475/read-only-visibles-directory%c2%b4s-file-names)