# Read folder files and save the names in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, file, directory

Im trying  to save all filenames in a folder in an Array so that i cant manipulate them later. My code is functional but i get an unexpected .DS_Store folder in my array. Does anybody knows how to get rid of that? and only read the visible files (.DS_Store is a System directory) in the folder? I know there is a filter method but i dont know how to implemet it in my code.

thanks for the help!

```
String pathLevel= "/Users/MaxRuizTagle/Desktop/hola/";


File file = new File(pathLevel);
String [] levelNames = file.list();
String [] matrix= new String[levelNames.length];
```

Comment: `file.list()` can also return a List of `File`-Objects. You can iterate over them and use `file.isHidden()`

Comment: You already asked a similar question yesterday and I even [answered you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28289545/1093528)

Comment: possible duplicate of [read files names from directory without System files(.DS\_Store)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290744/read-files-names-from-directory-without-system-files-ds-store)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read only visibles directory´s file names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289475/read-only-visibles-directory%c2%b4s-file-names)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `FilenameFilter`. In the `FilenameFilter#accept` method you can specify the condition that needs to apply for a `File` to be accepted. In your case, you don't want the file to be hidden.

```
File file = new File(pathlevel);
String[] levelNames = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return !dir.isHidden();
    }
});
```